# Trigger or insert

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: `product` and `UnproveProduct`

When a product is inserted, one row must be inserted for that new product into `UnprovedProduct`.

Which solution is better and why?

1. create a trigger after insert on `Product`
2. in the procedure when inserting a row into `Product` then also insert a row into `UnprovedProduct`

Answer (score 1):

I would pick #2.

Why?

- Triggers are notoriously annoying, and tend to cause unexpected issues - you can't really control how and when they're being fired, for one thing....
- If you already **have** a procedure to insert data into `Products` - just extend that and add the row into `UnprovedProduct` at the same time. You have much better control over what you're doing in a procedure (compared to a trigger)

Comment: Do triggers whos up in the triggers folder after they are created. Mine ran successfully but then nothing happens and I cannot find it in a folder either.

Answer (score 1):

It's a perfect use for a trigger. 
Triggers aren't that mysterious, nor are they difficult to predict. They're just a tool, and they follow very specific rules. In this case the trigger runs immediately after the record was inserted.

You can extend the insertion procedure, but the next guy won't use it and your records won't be properly inserted.

CREATE TRIGGER Insert_UnProvedProduct
ON Product
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN

INSERT INTO UnProvedProduct
(
field1, field2, field3
)
SELECT
field1, field2, field3
FROM INSERTED

END